# Ignore Field at serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

I have definied the fallowing Field in a class

```
[NonSerialized]
private TaskScheduler.TriggerItem _triggerItem;
```

Now, when the class should be serialized, I become the following Exception:

```
SerializationException Type “is not marked as serializable”
```

This is correct and I don't want to serialize this field. When I remove it, it is working.

I have also tried [XmlIgnore] - but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mark your *class* as `Serializable`

Comment: `Binaryformatter, XmlIgnore` strange mix.